# Пытаюсь реализовать каталог n-вложенности на PHP

Tags: php, html, дерево

В БД Postgresql есть таблица каталог 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой запрос выдает мне вот такой результат

```
WITH RECURSIVE r as (
    SELECT id,pid,description
    from razdel

    union
    select razdel.id,razdel.pid,razdel.description
    from razdel
             join r on razdel.pid = r.id
)
select * from r;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Моя цель на выходе получить следующий результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока что написал такой скритп на PHP

```
<?php
$resultArr =  pg_fetch_all($data);

function Tree($array,$sub=null)
{
    foreach($array as $v)
    {
        if($v['pid']==$sub){

            echo  " ".$v['description'] . "\n";

            foreach($array as $twov){
                if(($v['id']==$twov['pid'])){
                  echo " ".$twov['description']. "\n";
                  Tree($array,$twov['id']);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
echo "<pre>";
Tree($resultArr);
```

Он возвышает следующее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А дальше даже не пойму что и как сделать. Жду ваших наставлений. 
С уважением emrdev/

Comment: https://snipp.ru/view/200

Comment: Это вообще не то.

Comment: https://snipp.ru/view/107  а это?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
function Tree($array, $pid = 0) {
  if ($pid) {
      $haystack = array_filter($array, function ($item) use ($pid) {
        return (int)$item['pid'] === $pid;
      });
  }
  else {
    $haystack = $array;
  }

  if ($haystack) {
      echo '<div style="padding-left:15px;">';
  }

  foreach ($haystack as $item) {
    if ((int)$item['pid'] === $pid) {
          echo $item['description'];

          Tree($array, (int)$item['id']);
      }
  }

  if ($haystack) {
      echo '</div>';
  }
};

Tree($resultArr, 0);
```

Я не совсем уверен какой тип данных приходит к Вам в id и pid, поэтому на всякий выполнил приведение.

Comment: Спасибо такого результата смог добиться поставив уровни ). Но мне нужно это как то красиво запаковать в табличку или в список.